# What does VMware do when it is "Waiting for connection"?

Tags: windows-10, security, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

Today I noticed a screen saying "Waiting for connection" in VMware. I think it shows every time the VM boots, but it's usually very brief. This time, it hung on that screen for quite a while.

But what does it mean? Waiting for connection? Is it using the network somehow? What? Why? Is it phoning home with all my private data?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t use VMware but I can offer a good guess based on how other virtualization tools work:

The VMware “player” is most likely not a single self-contained app, but rather consists of several components that connect together. The actual virtualisation engine runs in a service and has no user interface at all — the VM management UI connects to it through some form of [local IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism, and the VM console display runs over another such connection.

This architecture is very common because it gives the developers quite a few advantages — the GUI can run with much fewer privileges than the core; the VMs or other services can remain running even as the GUI is closed; the same core can be controlled through several different GUIs and non-GUIs, e.g. command-line tools or network APIs.

So when you attach to a VM’s console, it is actually establishing something like a “remote desktop” connection to a service running on `localhost`. (In Microsoft Hyper-V, it is literally just a slightly tweaked Remote Desktop. In Libvirt/Qemu it is either VNC or SPICE.)

It might be using an actual a TCP/IP connection through the 'localhost' addresses (127.0.0.1, [::1]), or it might be using some OS-specific feature (named pipes, &c.). In any case, even using TCP/IP does not mean it is using an actual network (that is the whole point of a 'localhost' address).

Comment: Very good answer.